How to display bars in different colors in Vico bar charts
I'm using Vico bar charts in Jetpack Compose and I want to know how to display bars with values <0 in red and those with values >= 0 in green? Or, if possible, to use a dynamicShader in this case?
@Composable
fun BarChart() {

    val data = mutableMapOf<String, Double>()
    val dateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("ddMMMyy", Locale.ENGLISH)
    val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()

    for (i in Calendar.JANUARY..Calendar.DECEMBER) {
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, i)

        val startDate = calendar.time
        val startDay = fechaToRealmInstant(dateFormat.format(startDate))

        val lastDayOfMonth = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, lastDayOfMonth)
        val endDate = calendar.time
        val endDay = fechaToRealmInstant(dateFormat.format(endDate))

        val monthName = SimpleDateFormat("MMM", Locale.ENGLISH).format(startDate)

        val balance = realmViewModel.getMounthBalance(startDay, endDay)
        data[monthName] = balance
    }

    val labelListKey = remember { ExtraStore.Key<List<String>>() }
    val modelProducer = remember { CartesianChartModelProducer.build() }
    modelProducer.tryRunTransaction {
        columnSeries { series(data.values) }
        updateExtras { it[labelListKey] = data.keys.toList() }
    }
    val axisFormatter = AxisValueFormatter<AxisPosition.Horizontal.Bottom> { x, chartValues, _ ->
        chartValues.model.extraStore[labelListKey][x.toInt()]
    }

/*
    val model = CartesianChartModel(ColumnCartesianLayerModel.build {
        series(data.values)
    })

    val axisFormatter = AxisValueFormatter<AxisPosition.Horizontal.Bottom> { index, _, _ ->
        data.keys.elementAt(index.toInt())
    }
 */

    CartesianChartHost(
        modifier = Modifier.height(250.dp),
        chart =
        rememberCartesianChart(
            rememberColumnCartesianLayer(
                series(
                    rememberLineComponent(
                        color = Color(0xFFE91E63),
                        thickness = 24.dp,
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(6.dp).toVicoShape(),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            startAxis =
            rememberStartAxis(
                label = rememberAxisLabelComponent(color = Color.Black),
            ),
            bottomAxis = rememberBottomAxis(
                label = rememberAxisLabelComponent(
                    color = Color.Black
                ),
                valueFormatter = axisFormatter

            ),

            ),
        //model = model,
        modelProducer = modelProducer
    )

}


something like that
I want that, if a value is negative, the corresponding bar should be red and if it is positive it should be green,

Adding content:
val modelProducer = remember { CartesianChartModelProducer.build() }
modelProducer.tryRunTransaction {
                        columnSeries {
                            contentList.forEachIndexed { index, fl ->
                                series(
                                    List(contentReversed.size) { idx ->
                                        if (idx == index) fl else 0f
                                    },
                                )
                            }
                        }
                    }

Different color values per content Y value:
val colors = MaterialTheme.customColorScheme.progress()
val columnProvider = remember {
        val getColor: (Float, Float) -> androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color =
            { progress, threshold ->
                val topArea = 1f - threshold
                val green = threshold
                val moreGreen = threshold + (topArea / 2f)
                val orange = threshold * 0.80f
                val color = when {
                    progress >= moreGreen -> colors[3]
                    progress >= green -> colors[2]
                    progress >= orange -> colors[1]
                    else -> colors[0]
                }
                color
            }
        val columnAttributes = contentReversed.map {
            LineComponent(
                color = getColor(
                    it,
                    threshold,
                ).toArgb(),
                thicknessDp = thickness.value,
                shape = columnShape,
                dynamicShader = null,
                margins = Dimensions.Empty,
                strokeWidthDp = 0f,
                strokeColor = Color.TRANSPARENT,
            )
        }.toTypedArray()
        ColumnCartesianLayer.ColumnProvider.series(*columnAttributes)
    }

Adding to Chart:
 CartesianChartHost(
        chart = rememberCartesianChart(
            rememberColumnCartesianLayer(
                columnProvider = columnProvider,
....


